# how to invoke a setter method on an object (that coerces types)

Tags: java, clojure

I wish to write a function that interops with java objects

```
(assoc-obj <object> "<Prop1>" <Val1> "<Prop2>" <Val2>)
```

which is the same as

```
(doto <object>
     (.set<Prop1> <Val1>)
     (.set<Prop2> <Val2>))
```

I'm working with reflection:

```
(let [method (->> 
              (seq (.getMethods java.util.Date))
              (filter #(= "setDate" (.getName %)))
              first)
      arr (object-array 1)
      _   (aset arr 0 (int 1))
      d   (java.util.Date.)]
  (.invoke method d arr)
  d)
```

but I am finding that there are problems with type coercing.

Are there better/more clojurish ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod`. Here's a REPL demo:

```
user=> (def d (java.util.Date.))
#'user/d
user=> d
#inst "2013-12-04T05:47:33.560-00:00"
user=> (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
        d "setDate" (object-array (list 1)))
nil
user=> d
#inst "2013-12-01T05:47:33.560-00:00"
```

I'd consider everything about the reflector is an implementation detail (tweaks to method signatures might happen occasionally etc.), but this functionality is necessary in Clojure, in one form or another.

Comment: `(object-array (list 1))` looks a bit weird to my eye. What about `(object-array [1])`, or `(into-array Object [1])`?

Comment: Sure, `[1]` would be more usual in Clojure. For some reason I like `(list 1)` (or `'(1)`) better in this context right now, but I'm not claiming it's more idiomatic. (I'd actually prefer `(array 1)` instead of `(object-array ...)`, which is the ClojureScript way, but I guess introducing this function is off topic for this question...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a simple code transformation by looking at the example you have shown, so why not a macro:

```
(defmacro assoc-obj [obj & props]
  (let [psets (map (fn [[p v]] (list (symbol (str ".set" p)) v ))
                   (partition 2 props))]
    `(doto ~obj ~@psets)))
```

Comment: I thought about this as well... it is faster but data has to be defined upfront. functions are very useful because you can use apply